# How to Resolve TFS Issue when checking files in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc, visual-studio-2022

I have a project under source control using TFS and Azure DevOps.

It all works normally except for one thing: When I check in a file, I get this error message:

> TF10122: The path '$/KnowledgeBuilder/V2/$tf/1/1f8c47a1-8066-42d7-b56c-c9960b0ee7ea.gz' contains a '$' at the beginning of a path component. Remove the '$' and try again.

The check-in does in fact succeed, but I get three of the above error messages each time.  I can simply ignore this, but it is starting to get annoying.

It appears the folder in question is a TFS created and controlled folder.  I tried deleting the folder, but that remove the Project from Source Control, so I restored them.

Is there a way to resolve this?

This occurs in VS22 on a Blazor Server Project.  I have tried opening the Project in VS19, making a change, and then checking it in, and it works fine.  So, it must be something specific to VS22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone, sometime, at some point, added that `$tf` folder to version control. It should not be there, ever, under any circumstances -- that's the folder that TFVC uses to track local workspaces. That's why removing it messes up your workspace.

- Make sure any pending changes are committed or shelved first.
- Remove that folder *from source control*. Make sure the change is checked in. You might need to use a server workspace to do this so that the `$tf` folder isn't relevant.
- Use [`tf get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-command?view=azure-devops) to force a re-sync of your local workspace. `tf get /all /overwrite` should do the trick. If it doesn't, then just delete and recreate the workspace.
- Add `$tf` to your `.tfignore` file (although if memory serves, that shouldn't be strictly necessary -- I haven't worked with TFVC in a few years)

Comment: I opted to try the .tfignore file and that worked great.  I just created the file, added $tf/*.* as the only line and saved it in the root directory and now all is good.